# Pywinauto can't select the correct elements

Tags: python, ui-automation, pywinauto

I've been trying to automate a repetitive task with pywinauto. It involves loading and printing a file with a specific printer software. I've managed to automate launching, but getting stuck after opening the Open dialog. It raises a TimeoutError and ElementNotFoundError
[image: Interface Screenshot]

```
def print_file(app, file_name):
    # find the main window
    pexp = app.window(title_re = '.*Design.*')
    # ctrl+o for open dialog
    pexp.type_keys("^O")
    # this works - output attached
    pexp.print_control_identifiers()
    
    # this should work but it doesn't 
    dialog = app.window(title_re = 'Open')
    dialog.print_control_identifiers()

    # this should work but it doesn't either
    app['OpenDialog']['File name:2']['File name:Edit'].set_edit_text(file_name)
    app['OpenDialog']['ComboBox']['OpenButton'].click()
```

Output can be found below

https://pastebin.com/urxtXsK3

And error message:

https://pastebin.com/q0UNE1wM

**UPDATE:** I've managed to fill in the File name edit field, but can't find a way to click the Open Split button which looks something like this:

```
 |    | 
       |    | SplitButton - 'Open'    (L868, T563, R956, B589)
       |    | ['OpenSplitButton', 'SplitButton6', 'Open4']
       |    | child_window(title="Open", auto_id="1", control_type="SplitButton")
       |    |    | 
       |    |    | SplitButton - ''    (L941, T563, R956, B589)
       |    |    | ['SplitButton7', 'File name:SplitButton']
       |    |
```

I've been trying typing {ENTER} after the file name I want,but that didn't work.

Despite the above print_control_identifiers(), if I draw the outline of 'SplitButton6' it shows downward arrow next to Open. If however I `pexp['SplitButton5'].draw_outline()` it will draw the outline on the whole split button. Seems like there's something fishy.

I'm now trying to pexp['SplitButton5'].click_input() which closes the dialog, but doesn't show the next dialog as clicking the Open button manually would. any ideas? I'm guessing the poor quality of the software has a lot to do.

Calling some other methods on it gives mixed results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the type of 'Open' button. Indeed the type of this button can vary according to the situation: 'Button' or 'SplitButton'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David, the problem occurs even before trying to click on the Open button in the dialog as I'm not even able to fill out the file name edit field.

Comment: Maybe it's because OpenDialog is not a process from your application. In this case you have to use pywinauto.Desktop.

Comment: Any idea how to tell if it's not a proces of the application?

Comment: Normally this kind of Open dialog can be easily automated with pywinauto.Desktop. I am developing a  record/replay tool based on Pywinauto: https://pywinauto-recorder.readthedocs.io/ The development of this tool is still at a very early stage of development and the problem is that it does not work on al PCs. But maybe you can try it. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Hey David, I tried out Pywinauto recorder. Maybe it’s because I was using a windows vm in virtual box, but it crashed my machine. Is there an email I can reach you at?

Answer (score 0):

Use `click_input()`to instead of `click()`, for me it worked out.